# probability of survival at particular time points using randomForestSRC

Tags: r, random-forest, survival-analysis

I'm using `rfsrc` to model a survival problem, like this:

```
library(OIsurv)
library(survival)
library(randomForestSRC)

data(burn)
attach(burn)

library(randomForestSRC)

fit <- rfsrc(Surv(T1, D1) ~  ., data=burn)

# predict on the train set
pred <- predict(fit, burn, OOB=TRUE, type=response)
pred$predicted
```

this gives me the overall survival probability of all patients.

How do I get the survival probability for each person for different timepoints, say 0-5 months or 0-10 months?

Comment: I noticed the "pred$predicted" can be > 100. So it should not be "overall survival probability of all patients". Can anyone tell what is it for survival model?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The documentation on this isn't immediately obvious if you aren't familiar with the package, but it is possible.

Load data

```
data(pbc, package = "randomForestSRC")
```

Create trial and test datasets

```
pbc.trial <- pbc %>% filter(!is.na(treatment))
pbc.test <- pbc %>% filter(is.na(treatment))
```

Build our model

```
rfsrc_pbc <- rfsrc(Surv(days, status) ~ .,
                   data = pbc.trial,
                   na.action = "na.impute")
```

Test out model

```
test.pred.rfsrc <- predict(rfsrc_pbc, 
                           pbc.test,
                           na.action="na.impute")
```

All of the good stuff is held within our prediction object. The `$survival` object is a matrix of n rows (1 per patient) and n columns (one per `time.interest` - these are automatically chosen though you can constrain them using the `ntime` argument. Our matrix is 106x122)

```
test.pred.rfsrc$survival
```

The `$time.interest` object is a list of the different "time.interests" (122, same as the number of columns in our matrix from `$surival`)

```
test.pred.rfsrc$time.interest
```

Let's say we wanted to see our predicted status at 5 years, we would
need to figure out which time interest was closest to 1825 days (since our
measurement period is days) when we look at our `$time.interest` object, we see that row 83 = 1827 days or roughly 5 years. row 83 in `$time.interest` corresponds to column 83 in our `$survival` matrix. Thus to see the predicted probability of survival at 5 years we would just look at column 83 of our matrix.

```
test.pred.rfsrc$survival[,83]
```

You could then do this for whichever timepoints you're interested in.

Comment: I think the charge that this is "really poorly documented" is unfair. See the last example on the `?predict.rfsrc`. Uses cumulative hazard function to generate a survival curve: `exp(-pred.fit$chf)`

Comment: @BondedDust, you're right. I've updated my post in response.

Comment: @scribbles quick question on this topic.  Do the values in time.interest variable correspond to total time or the time an observation will survive from here on out?  "here on out" being the time when the survival algorithm was run.

Comment: I have problems using factors in the model. It doesn't run at all and seems very buggy.

Comment: great answer! can you please take a look at my question if you have time? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66684292/r-plot-individual-predictions thank you