# R: Plot Individual Predictions

Tags: r, plot, data-visualization, survival-analysis

I am using the R programming language. I am trying to follow this tutorial :https://rdrr.io/cran/randomForestSRC/man/plot.competing.risk.rfsrc.html

This tutorial shows how to use the "survival random forest" algorithm - an algorithm used to analyze survival data. In this example, the "follic" data set is used, the survival random forest algorithm is used to analyze the instant hazard of observation experiencing "status 1" vs "status 2" (this is called "competing risks).

In the code below, the survival random forest model is trained on the follic data set using all observations except the last two observations. Then, this model is used to predict the hazards of the last two observations:

```
#load library
library(randomForestSRC)

#load data
data(follic, package = "randomForestSRC")

#train model on all observations except the last 2 observations
follic.obj <- rfsrc(Surv(time, status) ~ ., follic[c(1:539),], nsplit = 3, ntree = 100)

#use model to predict the last two observations
f <- predict(follic.obj, follic[540:541, ])

#plot individual curves - does not work
plot.competing.risk(f)
```

[image]

However, this seems to produce the average hazards for the last two observations experiencing "status 1 vs status 2".

Is there a way to plot the individual hazards of the first observation and the second observation?

Thanks

EDIT1:

I know how to do this for other functions in this package, e.g. here you can plot these curves for 7 observations at once:

```
data(veteran, package = "randomForestSRC") 
plot.survival(rfsrc(Surv(time, status)~ ., veteran), cens.model = "rfsrc")

## pbc data
data(pbc, package = "randomForestSRC") 
pbc.obj <- rfsrc(Surv(days, status) ~ ., pbc)

## use subset to focus on specific individuals
plot.survival(pbc.obj, subset = c(3, 10))
```

[image]

This example seems to show the predicted survival curves for 7 observations (plus the confidence intervals - the red line is the average) at once. But I still do not know how to do this for the "plot.competing.risk" function.

EDIT2:

I think there might be an indirect way to solve this - you can predict each observation individually:

```
#use model to predict the last two observations individually
f1 <- predict(follic.obj, follic[540, ])
f2 <- predict(follic.obj, follic[541, ])

#plot individual curves 
plot.competing.risk(f1)
plot.competing.risk(f2)
```

[image]

But I was hoping there was a more straightforward way to do this. Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to modify the function `plot.competing.risk` for individual line, and plot over a `for` loop for overlapping individual lines, as shown below.

[image]

```
#use model to predict the last three observations
f <- predict(follic.obj, follic[539:541, ])

x <- f
par(mfrow = c(2, 2))
for (k in 1:3) { #k for type of plot
    for (i in 1:dim(x$chf)[1]) { #i for all individuals in x
        #cschf <- apply(x$chf, c(2, 3), mean, na.rm = TRUE) #original group mean
        cschf = x$chf[i,,] #individual values

        #cif <- apply(x$cif, c(2, 3), mean, na.rm = TRUE) #original group mean
        cif = x$cif[i,,] #individual values

        cpc <- do.call(cbind, lapply(1:ncol(cif), function(j) {
                cif[, j]/(1 - rowSums(cif[, -j, drop = FALSE]))
            }))

        if (k==1)
            {matx = cschf
            range = range(x$chf)
            }
        if (k==2)
            {matx = cif
            range = range(x$cif)
            }
        if (k==3)
            {matx = cpc
            range = c(0,1) #manually assign, for now
            }

        ylab = c("Cause-Specific CHF","Probability (%)","Probability (%)")[k]
        matplot(x$time.interest, matx, type='l', lty=1, lwd=3, col=1:2, 
            add=ifelse(i==1,F,T), ylim=range, xlab="Time", ylab=ylab) #ADD tag for overlapping individual lines
        }
    legend <- paste(c("CSCHF","CIF","CPC")[k], 1:2, "  ")
    legend("bottomright", legend = legend, col = (1:2), lty = 1, lwd = 3)
    }
```